# AJAX GET response is undefined

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

AJAX GET response is undefined but when I check the response body in browser's developer tool network tab, I can see the response data. Below is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "https://api.leroymerlin.it/product-api-v2/v1/allStoreStock/81262423",
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         beforeSend: function(xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-square-api-key', '96zoJArqvUf0');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-square-session-ID', 'WEB_2d2a266c-63b8-42fc-a122-b8e59d214d84');
        },
         success: function(data) {          
            console.log(data); // Verify the response
         }
});
```

Below is the image of network tab with data:

[image]

I am unable to understand this behavior. Please help and point out the mistake i am making here.

Comment: Your code works. You may want to not have your api key public http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/1hLjgmwc/

Comment: Go to the console tab you will see the response there as well and the response is not undefined

Comment: Your code is ok, try printing JSON.stringify(data) instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$.ajax({/*your settings*/})
.done(function(data){
  console.log(data)
})
```

Sure this will help.